# Linq return child entities not used in parent entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have the case whereby I have the following entities in my model.

```
public class Permission
{ 
  public int ID { get; set; } 
  public Operation Operation { get; set; } 
} 

public class Operation 
{ 
  public int ID { get; set; } 
  public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

The way my repository is set up I need to query the OperationRepository to find all those operations that have not been used in a permission. My EF Operation Entity has a navigation property back to the Permissions as an EntityCollection as below:

```
public partial class Operation : EntityObject
{
    public EntityCollection<Permission> Permissions
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

The method in my OperationRepository is:

```
public IEnumerable<IOperation> FindUnassigned()
{
    //query here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter your `Operations` where the navigation property `Permissions doesn't have any elements

```
.Where(p => p.Permissions.Count() == 0)
```

Comment: ...which is better achieved by `.Where(p => !p.Permissions.Any())`

Comment: My god I'm a complete newb! :) Thanks Geoff.